# Suppress dialog when using VBA to save a macro containing Excel file (.xlsm) as a non macro containing file (.xlsx)

Tags: macos, vba, xlsx, xlsm

How do I suppress the dialog that says "Visual Basic macros will be removed if you save the file in this format.  Are you sure you want to use this format?" (see picture below).

Essentially, I'm trying to use a macro to save a .xlsm file as an .xslx file?. I've tried all the dialog suppression code I can find and it isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub SaveWithNoMacros()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Clean Workbook With No Macros.xlsx", _  
       FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Here's the dialog:

[image: Excel Dialog]

As you might imagine, I need to convert a lot of workbooks and would prefer not to do this manually.

-D.

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18899824/1048539) work? I had a very similar situation recently. It may be OS:X handles this differently than windows for displayalerts.

Comment: @enderland, Good suggestion.  Hadn't thought of copying the sheets to a new/clean workbook and then saving.  It's a bit of a hack, but I might just implement it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is the correct statement to disable this dialog. But, as you have experienced, this does not work on Excel 2011. Sadly, there is no way to get around this when you use Excel 2011. Were you using any other version (on a PC) it would have worked just fine.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned in my original question that I was using a Mac (Excel 2011).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

Save as Type: (choose =>) Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)

Comment: The ask is to suppress the dialogue when saving an xlsm as xlsx.