# How to ignore Excel VBA errors (dialogs) when running from python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have a python script that uses win32com to run a VBA Macro on a Excel file.
The problem is that if there is an exception in the VBA Macro, Excel will open with a dialog box asking the user to continue.

This will block the rest of the python execution until the user answer the dialogbox.

[image: Error shown to the user]

As my application will be run on a server to generate multiple Excel file, there won't be a user to close the dialog box.

How could I ignore the Excel dialog box when there is an error so my application can keep running ?

Here is my python code :

```
import comtypes
comtypes.CoInitialize()

import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_file)

try:
    excel.Run('ReportModule.Compute')
    wb.Save()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Failed to run macro for {}.'.format(excel_file))
    logging.error(e, exc_info=True)

excel.Quit()
```

Comment: You should probably update your VBA Macro with code which silences those dialogs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088225/disable-all-dialog-boxes-in-excel-while-running-vb-script

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. But I would still prefer a more robust solution. In my case the macros will be written by different users. So if they forget/remove the safeguards, the server could still be blocked by a dialog box.