# Do not show "Saving" bar

Tags: excel, vba

So at the moment I have a macro that creates a series of pdf files and saves them in a folder, and it works fine but when I do "ScreenUpdating off" then every time a file is being saved a Bar showing that the file is being saved is opened and it does not close on its own.

I already tried doing

```
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

but it does not solve the issue, the bar still appears for each file and it wont close

Note:

I just tried

```
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
```

but its not working either

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add this :

```
With Application.DisplayAlerts = False               
     alerts.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False 
     alerts.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I bet that the alert you have is an overwriting alert so it might fix you issue.

Comment: No, this did not work, I still get 3 saving bars for each file and they wont close, this only started happening when I turn screen updating off, before that the bars would close without a problem

Comment: @sam0406 can you add a screenshot of the message pls

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48230950/11167163) ?

Comment: ive added a picture now, basically it shows that, the part that is blurred is the path of the folder where its being saved but then the screen never closes on its own

Comment: DoCmd.setwarnings false gives me an error of "object required"

Comment: @sam0406 try to add Access Reference

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: [Go there](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/add-object-library-reference-vba/)