# Execute a .exe file from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to create a macro enabled Excel file, in which, upon hitting the button, the Excel gets saved to `data.csv` into the same folder and an `.exe` file is to be invoked (which is again in same folder) which will access the `data.csv` for its inputs.

I prepared this, it created the `.csv` file, however, when the `.exe` runs, it is unable to access the `.csv` file (refer screenshot captured while the macro was initiated). The directory shown in that screenshot is the directory in which the `.exe` was created originally - this has nothing to do with current working directory. The code is shown below. I tried running the `.exe` file separately and it ran seamless, read the `.csv` file properly, so no issue with exe/csv files. it is just that while running from macro, the `.exe` is not searching the `.csv` in the correct folder.

```
Public Sub Save_CSV()
    Dim MyPATH As String
    Dim FileNAME As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim OldPath As String
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    Dim stat As Integer
    '*
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\dynjackup.exe"
    OldPath = CurDir
    MyPATH = ActiveWorkbook.path
    FileNAME = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    FileNAME = Left(FileNAME, Len(FileNAME) - 4) ' REMOVE XLS EXTENSION
    'FileNAME = FileNAME & "csv" ' ADD CSV EXTENSION
    FileNAME = "data.csv" ' any name can be set here
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' REMOVE DISPLAY MESSAGE: PREVIOUS FILE WILL BE ERASED
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileNAME:= _
      MyPATH & "\" & FileNAME, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
      CreateBackup:=False

    '
    OldPath = CurDir
    '
    ' Call ChangeCurrentDir(ActiveWorkbook.path, stat)
    RetVal = Shell(FilePath, vbNormalFocus)
    'Call ChangeCurrentDir(OldPath, stat)
    'ActiveWindow.Close
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Restore DISPLAY MESSAGE
End Sub
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Dont link to the code, paste it **here**.

Comment: Try adding `ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)` before you call `Shell`. Most likely excel has it opened exclusively

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think this wont work because the macro is running from ActiveWorkbook and will cancel immediately after closing and before he can run shell.

Comment: If this is the solution to the issue then I guess it needs to run from a different workbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use VBA SaveAs without closing calling workbook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899824/how-to-use-vba-saveas-without-closing-calling-workbook)

Comment: gents, thanks for all that comments.. if you see the screenshot - you could understand that the .exe file is called and it has started as usual but it is looking into a directory (c:\dyn-jack\lower\massparti-endce-fxd) for the .csv file. i dont know why the exe is looking into this directory. this was the directory in which the exe was compiled. but if i run the exe file by double clidking it, there is no issue, it finds the .csv file and the whole program works error free. i believe the issue is while running the exe through macro, it is not able to locate the .csv file

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most stable solution would be modifying `dvnjackup.exe` so it takes the complete absolute filename of the desired data file as a parameter. You could then pass this path in your `Shell()` call.

```vb
RetVal = Shell("""C:\dvnjackup.exe"" ""C:\Full\Path to\data.csv""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Note that I escaped both paths using quotes (the literal `""` in the string gives you a `"` in the result).

If you can't modify `dvnjackup.exe` you can try explicitly setting the working directory. But it seems you uncommented some code that does this (see the `ChangeCurrentDir` calls).

Anyways, you can change the current working directory like this:

```vb
ChDir "C:\Path\To New Working\Directory"
' No need to enclose paths containing spaces here
```

Hope this helps! :)