# Copy Open Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I want copy target macro to new location:

```
Dim strDes As String
strDes = "D:\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
FileCopy ActiveWorkbook.FullName, strDes
```

it occur error

> permission denied

How can copy an Excel file that is open?

Comment: If save as target file will can't working

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strDes` Using `SaveAs` will replace the current workbook with the new copy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899824/how-to-use-vba-saveas-without-closing-calling-workbook/18901568

Comment: @Tom: it is ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may copy the opened file using `Scripting.FileSystemObject`

```vb
Sub test()

    src = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    dest = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile src, dest

End Sub
```